# Struggling with EF CodeFirst 1 to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to be able to tag my `Movie` with a `Category`.

```
public class Movie
{
   public virtual ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

   public void AddCategory(string name)
   {
       using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
       {
           var category = dbContext.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) ?? new Category(name, dbContext);
           Categories.Add(category);
           dbContext.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
}

public class Category()
{
    public Category(string name, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        Name = name;
        dbContext.Categories.Add(this);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If the category does not exist, it is created and `dbContext.Categories.Add(this)` is called inside the `Category` c'tor.

There are no errors, but the new `Category` is not saved to my `Movie.Categories`.

I am guessing it is because my `Movie` class belongs to a different context? I am unsure how to structure this.

EDIT: If i was using a database first approach, this would result with a `Movie_Categories` table that has a `Movie_Id` and a `Category_Id`. Why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is a many-to-many relationship: One movie can have many categories and also one category can belong to many movies.

So the `Category` class needs a `public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies {get; set; }` property.

Your `Movie` class could look like this:

```
public class Movie
{
   public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

   public void AddCategory(string name)
   {
       using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
       {
           // get the movie object from dbContext so that it is attached
           var movie = dbContext.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == Name); // or match Movie by Id instead of Name
           var category = dbContext.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) ?? new Category(name);
           movie.Categories.Add(category);

           dbContext.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
}
```

And the `Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
  public virtual ICollection<Movie>() Movies { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set;}

  public Category(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }

}
```

Comment: does it matter that its an ICollection and not an ObservableCollection?

Comment: In object oriented design it it a good approach to program to an interface, not an implementation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) for more details.

Comment: I have existing movie categories in my database. When I read out my db initially, my OC<Categories> is populated correctly.  I only have issues on Add

Comment: in my real code my `Movie` and `Category` both share a base class that implement the `OC<Categories>`, so this has no effect

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the model differently. keep the dbcontext out of the model.

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies {get;set;}
}
```

Notice that I have a virtual collection of Movies within Category. It is this property and the virtual collection in Movie that set the many to many relationship.

You can add then add the category to the collection directly and call SaveChanges.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var movie = dbContext.Movies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    movie.Categories.Add(new Category() { Name = "Romance"});
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code above will be in some method outside the model classes, probably in your controller or your business layer.

Comment: this function is already inside the movie class. sorry if I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: @Julien Do you need this function separately? The AddCategory function that you have is equivalent to movie.Categories.Add(dvd);

Comment: this code does not work whether or not its in a function

Comment: one to many as evidenced by the `ObservableCollection<Category>` in my `Movie` class

Comment: @Julien Can you also share your Category model class?

Comment: a movie can have one or more categories. a category can belong to none or more movies. I cannot have a `Movie` inside `Category`

Comment: @Juien Then it is a many to many relationship and not a one to many. This is what I asked you earlier. Will update the answer for many to many then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75966/discussion-between-julien-and-praveen-paulose).

Answer (score 0):

code that ended up working

```
    public void AddCategory(string name)
    {
        Category category;

        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            category = dbContext.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            if (category == null)
                category = new Category(name, dbContext);
            else
                dbContext.Categories.Attach(category);

            var movie = dbContext.Movies.Single(x => x.Id == Id);
            movie.Categories.Add(category);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```